# Last Name First Name Switch with hyphenated names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know this has been asked several times and I have been able to find a partial answer using the results I have found on StackOverflow. I have a column that contains the name combination of "LastName FirstName"  I need the row to display "FirstName LastName.  I can make that happen using this SQL code:

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING('First Last', CHARINDEX(' ', 'First Last') + 1, 8000) +' '+ 
SUBSTRING('First Last', 1, CHARINDEX(' ', 'First Last') - 1)  AS Name
```

Now when I try to use this code using my data with this code:

```
SUBSTRING(Rtrim(Ltrim(name)), CHARINDEX(' ', Rtrim(Ltrim(name))) + 1, 
8000) +' '+ SUBSTRING(Rtrim(Ltrim(name)), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', 
Rtrim(Ltrim(name))) - 1)  AS Name
FROM
VW_MyView
```

I get my expected results but I also get an error message that states

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

I have tracked the error down to names that have a hyphen.  How can I deal with those hyphen during this process

Comment: Add Malcolm McDowell, Conan O'Brien, Jonathan Rhys-Davies and Carl van der Walt to your sample data!

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers believe about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . .

If you have only one or two names separated by a space:

```
select (stuff(name, 1, charindex(' ', name + ' ') - 1, '') + ' ' +
        left(name, charindex(' ', name + ' ') - 1)
       )
```

Note that this appends a space so the `charindex()` returns a valid position.